# Is it possible to read music file metadata using R?

Tags: r, metadata, mp3, ogg

I've got a bunch of audio files (let's say ogg or mp3), with metadata.

I wish to read their metadata into R so to create a data.frame with:

- file name
- file location
- file artist
- file album
- etc

Any way you know of for doing that ?

Answer (score 3):

You take an existing mp3 or ogg client, look at what library it uses and then write a binding for said library to R, using the existing client as guide for that side -- and something like Rcpp as a guide on the other side to show you how to connect C/C++ libraries to R.

No magic bullet.

A cheaper and less reliable way is to use a cmdline tool that does what you want and write little helper functions that use `system()` to run that tool over the file, re-reading the output in R. Not pretty, not reliable, but possibly less challenging.

Comment: I had a feeling this is where it would be going... Thanks Dirk

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3395878/4145280), you can use exiftool.

To use it within R, you can use `exifr` (`exiftoolr` is also good):

```
# download a public domain mp3 file from The Internet Archive
download.file("https://archive.org/download/Jazz_Sampler-9619/Kevin_MacLeod_-_AcidJazz.mp3", "jazz.mp3", mode = "wb")

install.packages("exifr") # if necessary

exifr::read_exif("jazz.mp3") |> 
  mutate(location = ls()) |> # this is assuming that the file is in the working directory. If not, then you want to replace ls() with "Directory"
  select(name = SourceFile,
         location,
         artist = Artist,
         album = Album)
# Output:
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  name     location artist        album       
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>         <chr>       
1 jazz.mp3 ~        Kevin MacLeod Jazz Sampler
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible, yes, easy, no.

You "could" use a combination of readChar and/or readBin on the file and parse out the contents.  This would be highly dependent, though, on parsing the [frame tags from the raw bytes of the ID3v2 tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2_Frame_Specification_.28Version_2.3.29) (and mind you it would change if it was a [version 1 tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#Layout)).  If would certainly be a lot of work to implement a straight R solution.  Take this [Python code](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/id3reader.py) for example, it's very clean straight python code but a lot of branching and parsing.

Comment: Thank you for the response Mark.  Your answer is valuable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exiftool` with `system` command available in R. Optionally, you can create regexp to handle the fields you need... If I were you, I'd stick with Dirk's advice (as usual) =)!

Answer (score 0):

Out here in 2021, I wanted to do this so I did the following...

1. Create a new playlist while in 'songs' view.
2. Select all songs and drag to the new playlist.  Highlight that playlist
3. File> Library>Export Playlist.  My default file was to save as .txt, if not, designate.
4. Open Excel to save as csv or read.delim() in r as the txt file is tab-separated
5. import to R