# How to change special file attributes using R?

Tags: r, file

On a Windows machine, when I look at any mp3-file and look at the properties of that file (mark the mp3, right click, properties), there are various subfields for the title, subtitle, artist, album, etc.

I am looking for a way to access these properties and change them. For instance, some files may indicate that the artist is "GreatArtist", whereas other files indicate "The GreatArtist" or "Great Artist".

I know I can change all of them manually by selecting all files that corespond to the same artist, right click and entering everything manually. I am looking for a way to automate this though so that it becomes easy for many folders, artists, and files, and R is my software of choice.

How can I access these properties using R? `file.info()` does not display these properties.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390262/is-it-possible-to-read-music-file-metadata-using-r) might, help but maybe it's outdated

Comment: Thanks! That does indeed help. A pity no one seems to have a package for that...

Comment: You might try writing the maintainer of the `tuner` package begging for a function to read the metadata of an mp3 file.