# How to read MP3 metadata?

Tags: r, metadata, mp3

What do you suggest I do to read metadata from MP3 files created with Audacity?

I routinely use R with RStudio.  A previous post to StackOverflow asked, ""Is it possible to read music file metadata using R?" Someone said 'You "could" use a combination of readChar and / or readBin.  I tried

```
data<- readBin(MP3file, 'character', 30000)
```

I parsed "data", sort of, using `rle(data == '')` to differentiate between the ID3v2.3 and the actual sound data.  However, what I got did not seem very informative.

I found other discussions recommending taglib-sharp, e.g., "How to use taglib to get information from a audio file", but I could not see how to use that.  I've seen other discussions recommending other things, other Python packages or C or C#.  I've used Python a tiny bit but not enough to know what to do here.

Help.  Thanks, Spencer Graves

Comment: Hi Spencer! Can you give an idea of what you want to see?

Comment: Closed as a duplicate: the previous question is old but does include answers that recommend `exiftool`, which is probably the preferred solution at present.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3395878/4145280), you can use exiftool (in this case, using `exifr`):

```
# download a public domain mp3 file from The Internet Archive
download.file("https://archive.org/download/Jazz_Sampler-9619/Kevin_MacLeod_-_AcidJazz.mp3", "jazz.mp3", mode = "wb")

install.packages("exifr") # if necessary

# read the exif data from it
exifr::read_exif("jazz.mp3")

# Output:
  SourceFile ExifToolVersion FileName Directory FileSize FileModifyDate         
  <chr>                <dbl> <chr>    <chr>        <int> <chr>                  
1 jazz.mp3              12.2 jazz.mp3 .          5090909 2023:08:10 14:53:41+14…
# ℹ 34 more variables: FileAccessDate <chr>, FileInodeChangeDate <chr>,
#   FilePermissions <int>, FileType <chr>, FileTypeExtension <chr>,
#   MIMEType <chr>, MPEGAudioVersion <int>, AudioLayer <int>,
#   AudioBitrate <int>, SampleRate <int>, ChannelMode <int>, MSStereo <int>,
#   IntensityStereo <int>, CopyrightFlag <int>, OriginalMedia <int>,
#   Emphasis <int>, ID3Size <int>, Title <chr>, Artist <chr>, Track <int>,
#   Album <chr>, RecordingTime <chr>, Genre <chr>, Copyright <chr>, …
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) which extracts metadata from a wide variety of media file formats, including MP3. It can generate CSV output and there are two R packages which use it: [exiftoolr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exiftoolr/index.html) and [exifr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exifr/index.html).

Example usage - with `exiftool` installed and in your path, from a command-prompt or terminal:

```
exiftool -csv yourfile.mp3 > yourfile.csv
```

And then read the CSV file into R using *e.g.* `read.csv()` or `readr::read_csv()`.

With `exifr` installed you might do something like this (untested):

```
library(exifr)

files <- list.files("path/to/your/mp3files", 
                    recursive = TRUE, 
                    pattern = "*.mp3", 
                    full.names = TRUE)

metadata <- read_exif(files)
```

Similarly with `exiftoolr` installed (untested):

```
library(exiftoolr)

files <- list.files("path/to/your/mp3files", 
                    recursive = TRUE, 
                    pattern = "*.mp3", 
                    full.names = TRUE)

metadata <- exif_read(files, pipeline = "csv")
```

Comment: ah curses I just got in there before you ^_^

Comment: You were first! I hope our answers are complementary, rather than mine just being a duplicate :)

Comment: re: exifr vs exiftoolr, I seem to remember reading that one of them used system(), and the other used system2(), with system2 being better, but I can't seem to find any mention of this anywhere now

Comment: tbh I think this whole question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390262/is-it-possible-to-read-music-file-metadata-using-r/